# How to stop and restart an app engine instance using httpservlet with firebase?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, firebase-realtime-database

In my android studio project I'm using an httpservlet to manage a firebase database. I want to call it every 6 hours so I'm using google cloud platform app engine free quota with a cron.xml to schedule it. I'm using [this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#writing_the_servlet_code) as a basis. This is the code I'm using:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;

    // I tried also tho stop instance with this Module and .stopVersion
    // ModulesService module = ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService();

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setServiceAccount(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/address"))
            .setDatabaseUrl("url")
            .build();

        try {
            FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception error){
            Log.info("doesn't exist...");
        }

        try {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }
        catch(Exception error){
            Log.info("already exists...");
        }

        // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("dbRef");

        valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // Remove listener
                dbRef.removeEventListener(childEventListener);

                // Stop module
                // module.stopVersion(module.getCurrentModule(), module.getCurrentVersion());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

        };

        childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                //Here I manage the database
                [...]

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}

        };

        // Add listeners
        dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
        dbRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    }
}
```

When it ends calls `valueEventListener` that removes the `childEventListener` and, as a `ListenerForSingleValueEvent`, it removes itself. The problem here is that the instance keep running and consume all my 9 hours of free quota before the next scheduled start.

I tried using `MyServlet.super.destroy()` but it destroys only the servlet container, not the instance; I tried also using `module.stopVersion()` in the `onDataChange` of the `valueEventListener`, this stops servlet instance but I don't know how to restart it.

Any suggestions? Can the async firebase listeners be a problem?

Edit:
This is my appengine-web.xml, I don't know if it may be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application>myApplicationId</application>
<version>1</version>
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
<manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```